# Tkinter checkbutton menu doesn't show check indicator

Tags: python, tkinter

When I create a Tkinter menu that includes checkbuttons I can't see the indicator when an item has been clicked. I should see something like this :

[image]

However I don't see the little check.

I'm on OS X if this is linked.

Using this code for example who works for someone else :

```
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()

var = StringVar(master)
var.set("Check")
w = OptionMenu(master, variable = var, value="options:")
w.pack()
first = BooleanVar()
second = BooleanVar()
third = BooleanVar()
w['menu'].add_checkbutton(label="First", onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=first)
w['menu'].add_checkbutton(label="Second", onvalue=True, offvalue=False, variable=second)
w['menu'].add_checkbutton(label="Third", onvalue=1, offvalue=False, variable=third)


master.bind('<Button-1>', lambda x: print("First:", first.get(), " - Second:", second.get(), " - Third:", third.get()))
mainloop()
```

**UPDATE**

If I set up a Menu widget (not an OptionMenu) then I'll be able to see the little checks. So this only doesn't work for OptionMenu widgets and MenuButton widgets

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I am on an OS X and for me it works.

Comment: I know it should work that's why I am surprised. Can it be linked to a bad installation ? I use ActiveTcl 8.6.3.1 from their website, OSX 10.10 and python 3.4 (but same problem with python 2.7)